# Selenium WebDriver with C# - How can I get all option value from a dropdown?

Tags: selenium

I am a beginner  to both Selenium WebDriver & Visual Studio 2017, I need help with:
Get all the option values from the dropdown and print it in the console.

```
<select id="FilterOrganization" name="FilterOrganization" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true"><option value="">Show All Organizations</option>
<option value="0013000000H9TkiAAF"> Associates, LLC</option>
<option value="0018000000ubNRhAAM">Test Health Systems</option>
</select>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("org - list")).Click(); 
SelectElement organization = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("FilterOrganization"))); 
IList<IWebElement> options = organization.AllSelectedOptions; 
foreach (IWebElement option in options)
{ 
    console.writeLine(option.Text) 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post any attempt you have made at coding this.

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.Id("org - list")).Click();
SelectElement organization = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("FilterOrganization")));
IList<IWebElement> options = organization.AllSelectedOptions;
foreach (IWebElement option in options){
console.writeLine(option.Text)
}

Comment: You should add your attempted to code to your post, it will show that you made an attempt and encourage more people to try and help you. I modified your post to include your previous comment of code you have tried.

Comment: Thank you! will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab them like this

```
var options = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("select > option"));
var optionValues = options.Select(elem => elem.GetAttribute("value")).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to install Selenium.Support nuget and then you can do the following:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;


// select the drop down list
var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("FilterOrganization"));
//create select element object 
var selectElement = new SelectElement(element);

foreach (var option in selectElement.Options)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(option.Text) 
}
```